# Confused: using Taylor series to find derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

TL;DR: read bolded parts

Lets say I have f(x) = sin(x^2) and I want the f''''''(0) (6th derivative). Using taylor series, this is really simple. We plug in x^2 into the taylor polynomial of sin(x), and get this:

[image]

Then the 6th derivative is 1/3! * 6! = 120.

I am confused because taylor series seems really unrelated; **there should be an equally easy way to do this just with derivatives and chain rule (no detour to taylor series)**. But when I bash it out, I don't get a simple solution.

[image]

(120 on the last line, typo)

**Why does taylor series come up in finding derivatives?**

Comment: typo in last line: should be $-24 -96 + 0 = -120.$  also, if I'm reading your earlier work correctly, corresponding taylor series typo: should be "Then the 6th derivative is... $-120.$ Re your question: "Why does taylor series come up in finding derivatives?"  If it did not "*come up*" that would invalidate the whole theory behind Taylor series.  Unclear what you are asking here.  Please re-state your question in a more mathematical context.

Comment: Because the coefficients of the Taylor series are made up exactly of the derivatives at a given point. Or are you asking why the coefficients are made up of the derivatives?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos i know both of those but shouldn't there be a way to find derivatives easily without taylor series

Comment: Easy is relative. When differentiating two chained functions, you get a product and a chain, so to differentiate again, you need product and chain rule. It will grow increasingly more complex with each iteration. Sixth derivatives of chained functions are just nasty. But from an algorithmic point of view, they're still easy: just apply product and chain rule mindlessly. It just takes a while.

Comment: Not trying to get technical. But an algorithm would be faster using taylor series substitutions, which is a little weird

Comment: I wrote a pretty detailed article about Taylor [here](https://brianbabu890.medium.com/) , maybe that will help you

Comment: aha @Vercassivelaunos check my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is (a-priori) no reason to believe, that calculating the sixth derivative of a function
will be easy.
In fact, if you were to fully write down the 6th derivative, this would be a really complicated expression.

The reason that the trick with the Taylor polynomial works so well here
is because $\sin(x)$ has a nice and well-known Taylor polynomial at the point $x=0$.

And for many functions, calculating the Taylor polynomial is also some work,
because it requires calculating derivatives.

And overall, Taylor polynomials already provide a lot of useful information about derivatives,
which is one of the reasons why mathematicians like Taylor polynomials.

Comment: For an **analytic** function, such as $sin(x^2)$, the function is **equal** to its Taylor's series so the derivative of the Taylor's series **is** the derivative of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, perhaps there is another  way!

$$ f= \sin(x^2) $$

Rewrite this as:

$$ f= \sin(u)$$

where $ u =x^2$, with  $ \frac{du}{dx} = 2x $ , $ \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} = 2 $ and$ \frac{d^3 u}{dx^3} = 0$

then:

$$ \frac{df}{dx}= g_1 = \cos u \frac{du}{dx}$$

At this point, we can apply the leibniz rule for derivatives ([I wrote an article on this](https://brianbabu890.medium.com/iterated-derivative-of-products-from-taylor-series-f362f20b1896) ),

$$ \frac{d^5 g_1}{dx^5} = \sum_{i=0}^5 \binom{5}{i} \frac{d^{i+1} u}{dx^{i+1}} \frac{d^{5-i} \cos u}{d^{5-i} x}$$

Now, the important thing to notice that the sum is zero except for $ i=1$ at x=0, (can you figure out why?). Hence,

$$ \frac{d^5 g_1}{dx^5} = f= \binom{5}{1} (2) \frac{d^4}{dx^4} \cos u |_{0}$$

Now rinse and repeat:

$$ g_2 = \frac{d^4}{dx^4} \cos u  =-\frac{d^3}{dx^3} ( \frac{du}{dx} \sin u ) =- \sum_{i=0}^3 \binom{3}{i} \frac{d^{u+i} u}{dx^{u+i}} \frac{d^{3-i} \sin u }{d^{3-i}x}=-\binom{3}{1}(2) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sin(u)$$

And again,

$$ g_3 = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sin(u) = -\frac{d}{dx} ( \cos(u) \frac{du}{dx}) = 2\cos(u) \binom{1}{1}+ \text{stuff going to zero}$$

Piecing everything together,

$$ f= \binom{5}{1} 2 \binom{3}{1} 2 \binom{1}{1} 2 \cos(u)$$

Evaluating 'officially' at $x=0$

$$ f(0)=120$$